# What is this plant, which has a spreading root system and purple, crinkled petunia-like flowers?

Tags: identification, flowers, perennials

[image]
<sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

This is a hardy perennial that grows up to 5' tall. It has a spreading root system and purple, crinkled petunia-like flowers. What is it?

Comment: Can you please post a photo showing the whole plant & one showing a flower (if possible)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That could be [Mexican Petunia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruellia_angustifolia). The flowers are usually purple or pink but also exist in shades of blue and white.

Comment: +1 Everything looks good, except the height (Mexican Petunia maxing out @ about 3ft/900mm), but I've learnt that plants don't necessarily obey their "stated" (textbook) sizes...

Comment: Mexican Petunia (whether we mean Ruellia cerulea or Ruellia angustifolia) does not appear to be hardy in Pennsylvania. I saw them both listed as zone 8 or higher. Otherwise, it does seem like a good match. Perhaps it gets lots of snow cover where it is growing.